# Shooting mass (people) into a blackhole to keep a spacestation in orbit?

Tags: science-based, physics

Due to contrived circumstances, A spacestation full of people is orbitting a blackhole. Over time the orbit is slowly deteriorating. They have no fuel to escape. Everything that isn't essential to the running of the space station has already been ejected. All that is left is the people. Would shooting some of the excess people periodically into the black hole help keep the station in orbit? Or do people not have enough mass to make any sort of difference to the orbit of something with such a huge mass? The spacestation only needs to be large enough to have a population that can replace itself without too much inbreeding.

Comment: Please elucidate on "Over time the orbit is slowly deteriorating".. If you are close enough to the black hole for frame-dragging to be measurable affecting your orbit, your crew has already been turned into red jelly by the tidal forces. " large enough to have a population that can replace itself without too much inbreeding." also conveniently ignores where the mass for the replacement population comes from. But yes. shooting people *backwards* not down, will accelerate your vessel, raising its orbit. Amount depends on how much mass, and how fast you can jettison it.

Comment: Can the spaceship survive an impact from a person at orbital velocity without breaking? If so I have really counter-intuitive answer for you.

Comment: sidenote: To stay out of the event horizon of a black hole, your station already is far enough out to *never* be in a spiral path into it...

Comment: As always, I'm happy to have my answer accepted, but it is generally considered a good idea to not accept an answer until ~24-48 hours have passed to maximise the number of people who can see and potentially answer your question. SE users are spread around the world in a bunch of different timezones and jobs, and people may be less likely to contribute to questions which already have an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, it's my first time posting on here. I did really appreciate your answer and thought it was such a unique concept. I'll remove the answered tag and keep the question open for discussion. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex no problem ;-)

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg) demonstrating the futility of sacrificing the humans after all the significant mass has been previously ejected.

Comment: You seem to think that humans can just breed more humans, so using them as reaction mass is self-replacing. This is false, because each human you expell takes away the mass of this human from your ecology.

Comment: as one of the downvoters, but not a closer - I have to say, be a little less drama queen next time. if u care about population replacement then things happen over a long period of time - so u get some free masses from a natural cause death rate, that's the first. The second shrinking station construction, due to population decline, gives u way much more mass to be ejected more like a 1:1000 ratio. 3) If u orbit decays due to interaction with accretion disc media and similar - u better use that mass and energy around u to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

> Due to contrived circumstances, A spacestation full of people is orbitting a blackhole. Over time the orbit is slowly deteriorating

Unfortunately for scifi drama creation, orbits generally don't decay. Things in low-Earth orbit often suffer from orbital decay, but that is because they're brushing against the fringes of the Earth's atmosphere which is not travelling at orbital velocities, and serves to drag things back down. Your black hole will not have an atmosphere, and the accretion disk will a) be travelling at orbital velocities and b) probably a serious hazard in itself.

Objects in lunar orbit can decay due to [mass concentrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy)#Effect_of_lunar_mascons_on_satellite_orbits) which provide a "bumpy" gravity well and interfere with orbit stability over time. Your black hole can't have these either... the horizon of the hole itself will be inevitably symmetric, if not actually spherical, and if there were any massive objects orbiting it (say, other planets or stars) your station would not have a stable close-in orbit in the first place, and *that* sort of unstable orbit generally ends with the station being flung *away* from the hole into deep space, because nature abhors a dramatic ending.

What I suggest you have, then, is something like a [statite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statite). These **do not orbit**, but instead balance some other force, such as solar radiation hitting a sail, against the pull of gravity. The radiation in this case might be provided by the black hole's [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk), which will heat up and radiate as it falls inwards towards the event horizon.

Let us imagine that the "contrived situation" here is damage to the radiation sail that holds the statite aloft. The damaged sail can no longer provide enough force to oppose the weight of the station. Solution? Reduce the weight of the station. This might include throwing people overboard who, because the station is not orbiting, will plummet satisfyingly down to the firey disk below where their freeze-dried carcasses will probably be incinerated.

It would only be useful to do this after getting rid of everything heavy and expendable, because the chances of the occupants of the station making up a substantial part of its mass are slim, compared to shielding, lifesupport, supplies, whatever else. But it is just about handwaveable.

Comment: If there is an accretion disk there will definitely be drag and orbit decay

Comment: @L.Dutch (for some reason I can't seem to @ you properly) the disk will be orbiting debris, and so will probably _not_ impart drag. It will, however, present a significant risk of collisions and will in all likelihood be quite hot and radiant towards the event horizon and so getting close to it has plenty of other risks. An orbiting object would have to be well clear of it (and so probably quite a long way from the hole) and a statite would want to be well clear of the plane containing most of the disk's contents.

Comment: The accretion disc itself doesn't (as I understand it) need to be symmetrical; it could have mascons and areas of greater/lesser radiation output (depending on how amenable the mass there is to fusion) that would require periodic stationkeeping. Of course then you get to the problem that humans are a bad way of storing reaction mass.

Comment: @Cadence there are some issues of scale here; suspect that an uneven distribution of mass an an accretion disk can only occur at reasonable distances from the black hole, and over short (astronomically speaking) timescales, due to the strong tidal forces that tend to smear things out. Really big masses, such as stars, limt the ability of your initial orbit to be stable, and building the OP's station in an already unstable orbit is making "contrived" do a lot of work...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to move to a higher orbit one should not shoot mass toward the attractor, but along the tangent to the orbit and opposite to the direction of motion, so to increase the orbital velocity.

The main problem with shooting humans, like with any other object, is that you rely only on the momentum you can impart to it. Quoting the expert on [oddly propelled rockets](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/):

$Thrust = Mass \ ejection \ rate × Speed \ of \ ejection$

With "burning fuel" the energy released during the combustion helps increasing the speed of ejection, making the entire process more efficient. If you have an overly powerful slingshot or the like to shoot out humans, you might get some $m/s$ of delta V at most.

Assuming the ships weights 10 thousand humans, and I am sure I am grossly underestimating here, by shooting 1 human at 10 km/s you would get a delta V of just $1 \cdot 10 /10000 = $1 $m/s$.

For a black hole the orbit velocities are for sure way higher than those I going to use in the following example, based on the Earth.

Considering that typical orbital velocities around Earth are around 7-8 km/s, you would need to fire 1000 humans per second to get something sensible. But then it would be pointless, since you would saving an empty ship.

To give you a [reference](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26927)

> For the ISS in particular, acceleration during reboost ranges from 0.008 m/s^2 to 0.0185 m/s^2, that is, 1/1200 g to 1/500 g, depending on whether the reboost is done by the Zvezda module or a docked Progress supply ship. Correction burns are typically done once or twice a month, and take several minutes to execute.

Assuming they last 10 minutes, they are getting 11 m/s of delta V, and the ISS is a feather with respect to the space station you are depicting.

Comment: So even if the spacestation was travelling at orbital speeds it would still need thousands of people a second to keep it at that speed? Would it not just stay at orbital speeds and only need a little topping off if there was some resistance slowing the spacestation down?

Comment: @alex not to keep it at that speed. It would NOT lose speed, naturally. But using humans as rocket fuel is a very inefficient way of speeding up a spacestation. (Unless you can make them very, very, very hot).

Comment: @ L.Dutch remember that the OP scenario is for a space station in orbit around a *black hole*, and in danger of "falling in" thus at least somewhat close. The orbital velocity will not be mere km/s. High relativistic, is more like it.

Comment: @PcMan, I know. I am just giving the example to show that already in an overly optimistic case it doesn't work.

Comment: @PcMan not necessarily that relativistic. For a small-ish black hole like Cygnus X-1, an orbit at ~1000km has a velocity of ~53000km/s which has a Lorentz factor of only 1.02. Of course, the spaghettification force acting on a standing human at that distance is ~112kN, so the station wouldn't actually have to enter the event horizon before Bad Enough Things happened for plot purposes. The tidal force situation is much less hazardous around the event horizons of supermassive holes like Saggitarius A*... there's just the accretion disk to worry about...

Answer (score 2):

If you have good timing, a computer than can do orbital transfer calculations, a nice strong ship with all the bulkheads intact that can take a few impacts, some remaining standard rescue equipment, a high-speed-slingshot, and crazy volunteers, you can save your space station by shooting people into space - **without killing anyone** - How? Read on... But first:

#### Shooting some people into the black hole will literally hasten your demise.

Orbital dynamics with single, short, efficient thrusts almost never behave as you might expect, many manoeuvres require thrusts that don't seem logical unless you are graphing the ellipses. A classic example: if you have two ships on the same orbital path but with some distance between them, to rendezvous them with minimal fuel consumption, one needs to first face away from the other and thrust (ie fire propellant **towards** where you want to go so that you move away from your destination), and that represents about half the delta v for the maneuver if it's done most efficiently. (This is a Hohmann transfer orbit).

Now for your exact situation, assuming "decaying orbit" is just screenwriter slang for "skimming debris or gas and that's slightly decelerating us", shooting someone straight towards the black hole, accelerating you away from it at a right angle to your current heading, will only make things worse, as it will perturb your orbit such that next pass you'll be closer - you'll transition to an elliptical orbit passing through the point you ejected the person.

**TLDR: If you're on the green orbit and launch people towards the black hole, you will bring yourself even closer to it on the next pass!**
[image]
Now you're hitting even more gas or suffering even more time dilation or... whatever made the green orbit bad ... it's now worse!

#### .... and so will shooting large numbers of people out the back of the ship tangential to the orbit.

L dutch's maths is spot on. You'd need to launch them really fast to accelerate you, and if you empty your ship for a little thrust it's kinda pointless saving the empty hull. If your orbit is circular, and you fire someone out the back, that will elongate your orbit into an eclipse with the same minimum distance to the black hole - no real benefit.

[image]

If you're doing the green circle and accelerate by launching some people, you'll transition to the yellow ellipse. Your ship will come back on its next loop to the same spot - still hitting the same distance from the black hole.

As implied by the image I stole from Wikipedia - you need to fire more people out the front later (about the same number of people and same speed) in order to get into a stabler, wider, orbit.

You need 2 people-launches minimum to step away from the black hole to a higher orbit.

#### But wait - there's a Hail Mary shot - you don't even need to kill anyone.

See this comfy looking inflatable sphere:

[image]

It's an [astronaut rescue pod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Rescue_Enclosure) meant for emergencies. Your space station has a few supersized versions of these left. They're made for the exact number of people needed for the calculations to work and be optimal. The "volunteers" get into these before they are launched into space.

You may notice the pattern to orbital transfers here - two accelerations are needed to transition orbit. Wouldn't it be convenient if that human we propelled into space came back round and hit the ship exactly right to apply the second acceleration? This nice sphere is squishy and helps ensure that a high speed impact doesn't rip through the hull (as well as thin layer of unobtainium to keep the G-forces survivable for the astronaut and make sure the thing doesn't puncture).

The transfer from red-to-green requires moving the ship onto the yellow ellipse by accelerating humans onto the blue ellipse:

[image]

Wouldn't it be really helpful if that blue path was just rotated ever so slightly such that it hit the station at the point where the station needs to transit from the yellow ellipse to the green ring?

By venting a little bit of air from the escape pod at a precisely calculated time and orientation, they'll be able increase the ellipse their escape pod is travelling on, transitioning to the purple ellipse. With timing and maths, they will hit the station on the yellow ellipse head on, decelerating them with the exact force that their orbit stabilises onto the green circle.

[image]

The acceleration needed for both transitions is almost equal, and the force applied on the ship by launching the escape pod is ballpark equal to the acceleration from the impact of when they collide later. It's unlikely to happen first loop (as the orbits all have different periods), but by timing everything carefully and letting everything do multiple elliptical orbits they can hit at a known time.

The hits also unlikely to perfectly transform them to the exact desired orbit, but the correction will be in the ballpark of what's needed. Since you have the people back and an improved orbit, theres no harm in feeding your new orbit into the computer and calculating another sequence of launch and impact, and repeat until safe. No ones dying for the manouver.

Pull them in; put a bit more air in, swap the vomit bags, and you can repeat this process. This doesn't violate any conservation of energy laws as it may seem on first glance: You are expending energy (using your reactor's nuclear energy or whatever to accelerate the rescue pod and the poor people), and that is being transformed into gravitational potential energy by slowly moving your entire ship further and further away from the black hole.

And as pointed out in the comments, if you dont think your people can survive the impact, the blue ring you launch them on is much easier for a subsequent rescue ship to retrieve them later, so this can still be a fatality free manouver.

Comment: It's bonkers, I like it.

Comment: i hope u aware that u orbital mechanics is wrong here. "...humans onto the blue ellipse:" - for this picture to happen they have to propel something with 2 orbit velocities and then the orbits of 2 particles will be clockwise and counterclockwise, and later on, the capture will bring momentum to the original value.

Comment: If nothing else, it'll be tough to gently decellerate your unfortunate reaction mass when they come past... a retrograde intercept from small projectile in a highly elliptical orbit sounds like a _firing solution_ rather than a rescue mission.

Comment: Still, throwing people into orbits from which they _may_ be recovered, if all goes well, seems rather less brutal than simply sacrificing them. You can have a +1 for the neat idea, though I'd edit out that bit about recovering the humans without the need for a separate rescue craft!

Comment: @MolbOg remebrr this is minus the energy loss from deformation of the hull, the air loss from the pod maneuvering, and drag from the gas or what other macguffin prompted this situation. It's unlikely to equally precisely the required delta v vector to return to the original momentum or perfectly stabilise the orbit, but it's ballpark, and able to be partially corrected by subsequent manouver.